# Search for multiple keywords in Picasa

Tags: search, picasa

I keep pictures of pools in Picasa. Each picture has the basic info in its file name. 
How can I search for pictures having ANY of several keywords?

E.g. I'd like to find pools that are *round* OR *square*.

From what I can tell, Picasa does a logical AND between each search term.

Answer (score 0):

General Picasa Search
Unless i read it wrong, if there is a word in the title you should be able to find it with a Picasa search
 Veiw -> click on 'Search options' this will give you a one word + search ability.

[image: image of picasa general search]

- File -> 'locate on disk'  and use the windows explorer search feature, this should result in a one word + search.
- For better searches if you have time, the tags panel feature of Picasa [bottom right] can be used to store custom tags which can be quickly added to your photo's as you use them.

[image: Image of picasa tags panel]

- You can use the type of file, if they came from the same source eg. png
- Tools -> Options -> Name Tags -> add check 'store name tags in picture'
- There is 3rd party search software [opensource or google 'free search' etc] but i am not sure they would be much help.
  Hope this helps in some way.